# No Sound on speakers hp dv6000

Tags: 12.04, sound, hp

I have no sound from my speakers with Ubuntu 12.04.2.(here's where stuff gets weird) I have sound with my headphones but they only work when halfway plugged in. The headphone jack has no problem when booting from my windows xp partition. At least I can get sound at all. I still have no sound from my speakers. any help?

Answer (score 0):

same problem here except sound works when headphones are plugged in all the way.

already tried this with no luck:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Insert this line at the bottom:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m4-3 enable_msi=1
```

Save. Close. Reboot. Check your levels in alsamixer.

```
alsamixer
```

- Press <kbd>F6</kbd> to select the correct soundcard.
- Press <kbd>F3</kbd> to show playback levels.
- <kbd>F4</kbd> selects capture levels [or use <kbd>Tab].</kbd>
- Use the left/right arrow keys to select and up/down arrow keys to change levels.
- M to mute/unmute.

Go to "System ->Preferences ->Sound" and make sure the correct soundcard is default and adjust your profile on the hardware tab.

No joy? Change that previous entry to this and reboot:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=hp-dv5 enable_msi=1
```